# I am unable to understand why this code is not working....even though it is working perfectly fine for "insert into student values" command

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

```
import mysql.connector as m

c = m.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="********", database="School")

if not c.is_connected():
    print("Connection Failed! Try Again")

else:
    cur = c.cursor()
    command = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE Roll_No %s"
    r = int(input("Enter the Roll Number to search for : "))
    cur.execute(command,(r,))

    cur.close()
c.close()
```

the error I am getting is

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000):You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '108' at line 1
```

(108 is the user inputted Roll_No to search for)

Comment: Don't you need `=` ?  Or some form  of equivalence operator?  `WHERE Roll_No 108` is invalid syntax...

Comment: Also, this approach seems to be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://bobby-tables.com/).  I know you're casting user input to `int`, but generally speaking, parametized queries are better than string replacement.  I'm not familiar with python and whether parameters are possible, but it might be something worth looking into

Comment: @devlincarnate this is actually using a parameterised query - passing a tuple of args and letting the `cur.execute` function from mysql driver handle safely escaping the values

Comment: @Anentropic : ah, ok!

Comment: Yeah got it. Understood my mistake. The code was missing "==". It is working fine now. Thank you @devlincarnate